# How to listen different click events in map using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to listen for different click events in mapbox using JavaScript? The following is the code for displaying a map using map box.

Can someone suggest how to listen to click events that differentiates land from water bodies?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Display a map on a webpage</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.2.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.2.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<style>
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZGphZWJvIiwiYSI6ImNrbzJoYjhodTAxeDUyb211eTF2anZ0bmQifQ.62m9LNQhEPZNCwqxEW9pPQ';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map', // container id
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // style URL
center: [-74.5, 40], // starting position [lng, lat]
zoom: 9 // starting zoom
});
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

I'm being able to listen to click events using the following code:

```
     map.on('click', (e) => {
        console.log(e.lngLat)
      })
```

But is there a way to differentiate coordinates land from water bodies?

Answer (score 3):

if you try this:

```
map.on('load', function () {
    let style = map.getStyle();
})
```

then you can see all the details about the style such as sources, layers, glyphs and etc .
Also for listening to click events on different layers, you can just use:

```
 map.on('click', 'land', function (e) {
     // some code
 });
```

or you can query the rendered features within multiple layers by code below:

```
map.on('click', function (e) {
    let featureSelected = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {layers: ['land', 'water']
    });
});
```